# Jade layout can not be found in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express, pug

### My settings:

My directory structrue looks like this:

```
/views/
   |-- index.jade
   |-- layout.jade
   /account/
      |-- login.jade
      |-- register.jade
```

I have configured my view engine as follows:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

*Edit:* I also have

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

My controllers look like:

```
app.get('/login', redirectIfLogined, function(req, res){
    res.render('account/login', { title: "Login", redir: req.query.redir});
});

app.get('/register', redirectIfLogined, function(req, res) {
    res.render('account/register', { title: "Register"});
});
```

---

### My issue

With settings as described I am getting a 500 error:

```
500 Error: failed to locate view "layout"
at Function.compile (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:58:15)
at ServerResponse._render (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:414:18)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:315:17)
at ServerResponse._render (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:429:10)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:315:17)
at D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\controllers\accountController.js:6:13
at callbacks (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
at D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\modules\middleware\account.js:27:9
at callbacks (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:272:11)
at param (D:\dev\Azznomad\express-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:11)
```

As soon as I am copying my `layout.jade` file into the `/account/` folder it works perfectly. Unfortunately this would make no sense since it forced me to have redundant layout files.

**What am I missing?**

---

*Btw. this code snipplets are from AzzNomad's [express/mongoose template](https://github.com/AzzNomad/express-template) which is very helpful in order to learn express with mongoose.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put

`extends ../layout`

in your view under accounts since layout is not in the same folder.

Comment: totally worked for me: I had a view that I was AJAXing into another page and wanted it to be in Jade/served from views/partials - so make sure any extends/includes are attached correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should also set views path, since it is in another directory besides application script.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: Forgot to add this, but I already have added this to my code, so there is something else I am missing here. Any othe suggestions ? :-)